# nativescript console.log() is not working

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I can't see console logs in my nativescript/angular app in a super simple scenario - on button tap I have console.log('hello').

So far I've tried using Sidekick, VS Code, `tns run android`, `tns debug android`, `tns device log`, `adb logcat` and bunch of other commands I found in Google.

I am using nativescript 6.3.0 and my environment is correct according to `tns doctor`/`tns info`

I wonder if anyone had similar problem?

Comment: After hitting  `tns run android` do you see other system / framework generated logs Or nothing apart from app launch?

Comment: I see a bunch of logs, the last 2 of which are: Successfully synced application org.nativescript.xxxxxx on device emulator-xxxx.
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Comment: @armache I have similar problem, did you manage to fix this? If so, how you did it?

Comment: I see this has been viewed a good bit. I've had the problem on iOS on and off for a year. Console log worked fine yesterday; when I picked back up today--no code changes--can't get logs for anything. tns 6.5.0, etc.